# Centering Layout With Padding - rounding error

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Nested layouts in xamarin seem to be biased to the left of the screen. I'm assuming this is a dp to pixel rounding bias or something?

Can anyone confirm, is there a work around or solution?

Although my example uses Absolute layout the problem seems to be on all layouts.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinTest
{
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AbsoluteLayout child = layout;
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(child, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(child, new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i =0;i<100; i++)
            {
                child = addLayout(child, rand) ;
            }

            AbsoluteLayout abs = new AbsoluteLayout();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(abs, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(abs, new Rectangle(0, 0, 0.5, 0.5));
            abs.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
            layout.Children.Add(abs);
        }

        private AbsoluteLayout addLayout(AbsoluteLayout parent, Random rand)
        {
            AbsoluteLayout abs = new AbsoluteLayout();
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(abs, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
            AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(abs, new Rectangle(0,0,1,1));
            abs.Padding = new Thickness(2.0);
            abs.BackgroundColor = new Color(rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble(), rand.NextDouble());
            parent.Children.Add(abs);

            return abs;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="XamarinTest.Page1">
  <AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="White" x:Name="layout">

  </AbsoluteLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Screen shot (if it uploads):

[image: layout centering problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are seeing differences in the emulator's rendering vs. an issue with the `Forms` code running on Android as the DPI of the simulate screen can throw offsets into the mix.   ​

iOS Simulator does a great job at rendering at a 1:1 based upon the actual devices' DPI and then down-sampling the display based upon your view settings and your code will always render those `StackLayout` at the requested position.

If you look at the your code running on two (OS-X-based) emulators using a DPI that divides "cleanly" to the pixels on the physical screen of the emulator:

[image]

[image]

Versus one that does not:

[image]

If you have the paid-version of GenyMotion's emulator, there is a one-2-one scaling option that provides a similar experience as the iOS simulator.

Moral of the story, use physical devices for final checks of your layouts. A great way is to use Xamarin's Test Cloud and add a screenshot capture to each of your app's Form pages

Comment: V interesting I will have to check. However, I believe we first noticed the issue on a physical device (although it could have been a different cause) what screen res are your emulators using?

Comment: Ps. Completely seperate question, our test cloud ios tests have stopped working, they cant seem to pick up on the accesablity id any more! (Using style id suggest code from.xamarin site) Do you use this? Is it working for you?

Comment: double checked on device, you are absolutely correct!

Comment: @Ewan Glad to hear it... regarding the iOS tests, I have clients that use it and have not hear anything that that the Ids are not working...

Comment: thanks, its good to know its working for someone else and not just a xamarin update or something. we managed to debug it a bit and, it is something else

Comment: @Ewan FYI: Start using `Margin` vs `Padding` in Forms 2.2+

Comment: @SushiHangover it shouldn't be Margin vs Padding. They cause different effects. Unfortunately at the point it's not done as anyone using it would expect it to behave. At least i am experiencing quite some bugs

Comment: @Dbl Where people are using `Padding` to apply a margin to child elements, in Forms 2.2+ you want to use `Margin`. Prior to 2.2 there was not much of an option, but 95% of the time that I see Padding being used, Margin is really want you are looking for, and your Forms layout speeds will greatly benefit for using it.

Comment: @SushiHangover That's still not what margin was intended for. There's a reason both exist. The only reason margin was finally reintroduced is because people used nesting to mimic margin, which bloated the view tree. there's still perfectly valid reasons for intentionally using padding. Just saying someone should use margin instead of padding is plain wrong. that's all i'm saying. Both have seperate use cases